# Is the USA the largest trading partner of Vietnam nowadays?

Tags: united-states, trade, seymour-hersh

According to Seymour Hersh, the fall of Saigon was irrelevant (wrt. to containing China etc.) [because](https://youtu.be/742AbBTQ8CU?t=2650)

> We're the largest trading partner of Vietnam now.

By "we" he surely means the USA. Is this true, is the USA the largest trading partner of Vietnam?

Comment: to summarise the answers: it depends on how you calculate it. If you look only at Vietnam's exports, the US are their largest trading partner, if you look at imports (as well) it's China.

Comment: Of course phrasing the same statement as "USA accounts for less than a quarter of total trade volume" doesn't quite have the same ring to it as the original statement.

Comment: @Marianne013 Why?  What does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 37):

Vietnam exports more (by value) to United States than any other country. It imports more from China and several other countries than it does from the USA.

The [WorldBank](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountrySnapshot/en/VNM) puts United States as the top market as a buyer from Vietnam, and fifth top market as a seller to Vietnam:

> Vietnam top 5 Export and Import partners
>
> | Market | Trade (US$ Mil) | Partner share(%) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | United States | [77,072](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Indicator/XPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/USA/Product/All-Groups) | [27.38](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/USA/Indicator/XPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | China | [48,880](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Indicator/XPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/CHN/Product/All-Groups) | [17.37](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/CHN/Indicator/XPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Japan | [19,269](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Indicator/XPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/JPN/Product/All-Groups) | [6.85](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/JPN/Indicator/XPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Korea, Rep. | [19,125](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Indicator/XPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/KOR/Product/All-Groups) | [6.80](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/KOR/Indicator/XPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Hong Kong, China | [10,436](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Indicator/XPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/HKG/Product/All-Groups) | [3.71](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/HKG/Indicator/XPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
>
> | Exporter | Trade (US$ Mil) | Partner share(%) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | China | [84,198](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Indicator/MPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/CHN/Product/All-Groups) | [32.22](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/CHN/Indicator/MPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Korea, Rep. | [46,862](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Indicator/MPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/KOR/Product/All-Groups) | [17.93](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/KOR/Indicator/MPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Japan | [20,277](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Indicator/MPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/JPN/Product/All-Groups) | [7.76](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/JPN/Indicator/MPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | Other Asia, nes | [16,704](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Indicator/MPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/OAS/Product/All-Groups) | [6.39](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/OAS/Indicator/MPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |
> | United States | [13,764](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Indicator/MPRT-TRD-VL/Partner/USA/Product/All-Groups) | [5.27](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/VNM/StartYear/2016/EndYear/2020/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/USA/Indicator/MPRT-PRTNR-SHR) |

---

The [CIA Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/field/exports-partners) puts the top **export partners** as:

> United States 23%, China 14%, Japan 8%, South Korea 7% (2019)

However, it doesn't directly reference the source, so it is difficult to trust.

---

[Reuters reported in 2021](https://www.reuters.com/markets/asia/vietnams-2021-exports-climb-19-record-trade-surplus-with-us-2022-01-13/) that:

> China is Vietnam's largest trading partner, on which the Southeast Asian country relies heavily for materials and equipment for its labour-intensive manufacturing. Imports from China rose 30% to $110 billion.

(Note this is based on **imports** into Vietnam)

---

The [Observatory of Economic Complexity (OEC)](https://oec.world/en/profile/country/vnm) provides visuals with the USA as the biggest export market, and China the biggest import market:

- Exports (2020)

> [image]

- Imports (2020)

> [image]

Comment: **Comments about how to calculate "top" have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144553/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-is-the-usa-the-largest-trading-partner-of-vi); please do not continue that discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 14):

Assuming Vietnam+ reflects the way official statistics are usually done over there, it [says](https://en.vietnamplus.vn/vietnams-trade-with-biggest-partners-in-2022/248239.vnp):

> Data from the General Department of Customs shows in 2022, China is Vietnam's largest trading partner with a total two-way trade turnover of 175.57 billion USD, followed by the US (123.86 billion USD), the Republic of Korea (86.38 billion USD) and Japan (47.61 billion USD).

GDCV is the official agency of Vietnam, but finding that data on their [site](https://www.customs.gov.vn/index.jsp?ngon_ngu=en) can be a bit of a challenge.